# Automatically play Audio object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a audio object with `new Audio()`.

```
const audio = new Audio()
```

I know, to play a audio user interaction is mandatory. So I tried with the following code.

```
audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", () => {
   audio.play()
});
```

But it throws the **Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first** error again. How to solve this?

Comment: You can only call `play` after user interaction, e.g. a click.

Comment: Browsers don't let you auto-play audio/video without the user interacting with the page.  This is to prevent things like ads, though there is a workaround that _should_ work.  On your `<audio>` element, try adding `autoplay` and `muted`.  Something like `<audio autoplay muted src=""></audio>`.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability

Comment: Yeah, I know window need a user interaction. That's why added 'canplaythrough' event listener. I need to play the audio as soon as possible. In my case, this is not a dom audio element. and I don't thing there is a way to add muted attribute to audio object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Unmitigated mentioned in the comment, user interaction is mandatory to play an audio. If you want to play the user interaction, modify the code as below

```
audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", () => {
   audio.play().catch(e => {
      window.addEventListener('click', () => {
         audio.play()
      })
   })
});
```

**Edited**
Add `{ once: true }` to trigger only once.

```
audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", () => {
   audio.play().catch(e => {
      window.addEventListener('click', () => {
         audio.play()
      }, { once: true })
   })
});
```

Comment: You'll probably want to add `{ once: true }` as the third parameter of `.addEventListener()` so you don't start playing every time the user clicks anywhere. (Especially after the audio has been paused.)

Answer (score 2):

In order to be allowed to autoplay, either the user needs to have interacted with the page or the audio/video needs to be muted.

You can try:

```
let audio = new Audio('a_file');

audio.muted = true;
audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", () => {
   audio.play()
});
```